# Constructing numeric flag with switch command

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a data frame with a variable `ind_percentiles`, which assumes values from 1 to 100. I want to create a numeric categorical variable—`ind_Q`—which takes the values of:

- 1 if `ind_percentiles` < 25
- 2 if `ind_percentiles` 26 - 50
- 3 if `ind_percentiles` 51 - 75
- 4 if `ind_percentiles` 76 - 100

I want to accomplish this using a `switch` statement rather than an `if: else`.

```r
Data$IMD_Q = 0

switch(Data$Index_Q,
       1 = {Data$ind_percentiles <= 25},
       2 = {Data$ind_percentiles > 25},         
       3 = {Data$ind_percentiles > 50},  
       4 = {Data$ind_percentiles > 75})
```

Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I missed it but what language are you working with?

Comment: @Josiah: It appears to be R, so I’ve suggested an edit which includes that tag. (Along with some additional reformatting.)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using `switch()`? If not, you could use `cut()` to easily get your desired result, e.g. `cut(1:100, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25), labels = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Josiah. Yes I' m using R studio 3.6. I'm new to R, but am taking code suggested in a previous post and trying to tweak it. But when i run the code I am told